# Is it possible to cancel unfinished goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Consider a group of check works, each of which has independent logic, so they seem to be good to run concurrently, like:

```golang
type Work struct {
    // ...
}

// This Check could be quite time-consuming
func (w *Work) Check() bool {
    // return succeed or not

    //...
}

func CheckAll(works []*Work) {
    num := len(works)
    results := make(chan bool, num)
    for _, w := range works {
        go func(w *Work) {
            results <- w.Check()
        }(w)
    }

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        if r := <-results; !r {
            ReportFailed()
            break;
        }
    }
}

func ReportFailed() {
    // ...
}
```

When concerned about the `results`, if the logic is *no matter which one work fails, we assert all works totally fail*, the remaining values in the channel are useless. Let the remaining unfinished goroutines continue to run and send results to the channel is meaningless and waste, especially when `w.Check()` is quite time-consuming. The ideal effect is similar to:

```golang
    for _, w := range works {
        if !w.Check() {
            ReportFailed()
            break;
        }
    }
```

This only runs necessary check works then break, but is in sequential non-concurrent scenario.

So, is it possible to cancel these unfinished goroutines, or sending to channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cancelling a (blocking) send

Your original question asked how to cancel a send operation. A send on a channel is basically "instant". A send on a channel blocks if the channel's buffer is full and there is no ready receiver.

You *can* "cancel" this send by using a `select` statement and a `cancel` channel which you close, e.g.:

```
cancel := make(chan struct{})

select {
case ch <- value:
case <- cancel:
}
```

Closing the `cancel` channel with `close(cancel)` on another goroutine will make the above select abandon the send on `ch` (if it's blocking).

But as said, the send is "instant" on a "ready" channel, and the send first evaluates the value to be sent:

```
results <- w.Check()
```

This first has to run `w.Check()`, and once it's done, its return value will be sent on `results`.

#### Cancelling a function call

So what you really need is to cancel the `w.Check()` method call. For that, the idiomatic way is to pass a `context.Context` value which you can cancel, and `w.Check()` itself must monitor and "obey" this cancellation request.

See [Terminating function execution if a context is cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002729/terminating-function-execution-if-a-context-is-cancelled/62002965#62002965)

Note that your function must support this explicitly. There is no implicit termination of function calls or goroutines, see [cancel a blocking operation in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go/28240299#28240299).

So your `Check()` should look something like this:

```
// This Check could be quite time-consuming
func (w *Work) Check(ctx context.Context, workDuration time.Duration) bool {
    // Do your thing and monitor the context!

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return false
    case <-time.After(workDuration): // Simulate work
        return true
    case <-time.After(2500 * time.Millisecond): // Simulate failure after 2.5 sec
        return false
    }
}
```

And `CheckAll()` may look like this:

```
func CheckAll(works []*Work) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    num := len(works)
    results := make(chan bool, num)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i, w := range works {
        workDuration := time.Second * time.Duration(i)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(w *Work) {
            defer wg.Done()
            result := w.Check(ctx, workDuration)
            // You may check and return if context is cancelled
            // so result is surely not sent, I omitted it here.
            select {
            case results <- result:
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            }
        }(w)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results) // This allows the for range over results to terminate
    }()

    for result := range results {
        fmt.Println("Result:", result)
        if !result {
            cancel()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
CheckAll(make([]*Work, 10))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kFLZQw32dxD)):

```
Result: true
Result: true
Result: true
Result: false
```

We get `true` printed 3 times (works that complete under 2.5 seconds), then the failure simulation kicks in, returns `false`, and terminates all other jobs.

Note that the `sync.WaitGroup` in the above example is not strictly needed as `results` has a buffer capable of holding all results, but in general it's still good practice (should you use a smaller buffer in the future).

See related: [Close multiple goroutine if an error occurs in one in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500836/close-multiple-goroutine-if-an-error-occurs-in-one-in-go/45502591#45502591)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **No**.

You can not cancel or close any goroutine unless the goroutine itself reaches the `return` or end of its stack.

If you want to cancel something, the best approach is to pass a `context.Context` to them and listen to this `context.Done()` inside of the routine. Whenever context is canceled, you should `return` and the goroutine will automatically die after executing defers(if any).

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Work struct {
    // ...
    Name string
    IsSuccess chan bool
}

// This Check could be quite time-consuming
func (w *Work) Check() {
    // return succeed or not

    //...
    if len(w.Name) > 0 {
        w.IsSuccess <- true
    }else{
        w.IsSuccess <- false
    }

}


//堆排序
func main() {
    works := make([]*Work,3)
    works[0] = &Work{
        Name: "",
        IsSuccess: make(chan bool),
    }
    works[1] =  &Work{
        Name: "111",
        IsSuccess: make(chan bool),
    }
    works[2] =&Work{
        Name: "",
        IsSuccess: make(chan bool),
    }

    for _,w := range works {
        go w.Check()
    }

    for i,w := range works{
        select {
        case checkResult := <-w.IsSuccess :
            fmt.Printf("index %d checkresult %t \n",i,checkResult)
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/479AN.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).